# unexpected token with iframe buster busting

Tags: javascript, iframe

While working with the iframe buster busting code example from this paper https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/framebust.pdf  , i keep coming up with an error of "unexpected token '<'"

Obviously this is reference to the last line in the code (the iframe line) but i cant seem to figure out how to resolve this

```
var prevent_bust = 0  
window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
setInterval(function() {  
if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
prevent_bust -= 2  
window.top.location = 'http://httpstat.us/204'  
}  
}, 1);  
<iframe src="website to redirect to">
```

EDIT::

the code above is within a JS file.  Looking at the paper (url link) it states that the code above is needed in order to make the exploit work, but how are you suppose to put an  into a JS file?

Comment: You cannot embed HTML code directly within JavaScript.

Comment: Which page (and section) is that code sample from?

Comment: `<iframe src="website to redirect to">` not sure what this is for, but that is what is causing the issue as that is HTML not JS.

Comment: Right.  The paper i linked to addresses the code i wrote, stating this was code that could get around iframe busting.  But in the code above the last line is needed to direct to once the exploit is finished.  But i dont understand how to get this to work because its within a JS file and , this is html code.

How could i get this, or something similar to work in a JS file ?